# How can I avoid failed validation if no image is uploaded to paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, paperclip

In my application, a user has the option to upload a bulk of specifically organized photos.  However, when the user does not upload all of them, I receive an error stating "Validation failed: picture_one can't be blank, picture_two can't be blank, etc.".

How can I only pass the parameter if the picture exists?

Right now I have `picture_one => params[:picture_one] || false`, but that does not seem to work.

**Edit**

Here is my model code

```
has_attached_file :picture_one, :storage => :s3
validates_attachment :picture_one, :presence => true, :content_type => { :content_type => ["image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png"] }, :size => { :in => 0..4.megabytes }
```

Comment: Can you add your model code to show the current validations?

Comment: @crsven model code added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want a `presence` validation on the photo, since it's optional. I would suggest removing `:presence => true` from the validation line, so you will still validate the other attributes, but not the existence of the photo.

More info on validations [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)